# EXISTS query don't work. Error in Syntax

Tags: sql, exists

I tried this query but I can't get it to work:

It says that there's a syntax error near EXISTS.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerID EXIST IN (SELECT *, CustomerID FROM Orders);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is right. You even wrote `Exists` in your question but in the example code you wrote `exist` with no `s` on the end. See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) for the proper syntax

You need to correlate the outer query with the sub query in the `exists`. It doesn't matter what columns you select because by rule they are not allowed to be evaluated (i.e. `select *` is fine)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Orders where Orders.CustomerID = C.CustomerID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders);
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you please direct me to the right syntax for Exists?

Comment: see @Robert Navarro answer, that's the most typical, but may vary depending on your sql platform.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `JOIN`?

```
SELECT
    Customers.*
FROM
    Customers
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

If you really do want to use `EXSITS`, the syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Customers.*
FROM
    Customers
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID);
```

And for good measure using `IN`:

```
SELECT
    Customers.*
FROM
    Customers
WHERE
    CustomerID IN (SELECT Orders.CustomerID FROM Orders);
```

If you are on MySQL I'd encourage you to run all 3 with the `EXPLAIN` statement, so you can see how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct exists syntax, performance wise, this is A LOT better than an IN statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 'X' FROM Orders o WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID);
```